# Uncaught TypeError: windowWidth is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: windowWidth is not a function - how do i fix, please see below code - i trying to screate about us page that is responsive with two images?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import classes from './styles.module.scss';
import chair from './chair.png';
import chairmob from './chairmob.png';

const About = () => {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  const imageUrl = windowWidth() >= 600 ? chair : chairmob;

  const handleWindowResize = () => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    };
  });

  return (
    // <div className={classes.About}>
    <div className="About" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}>
      <div className="About-content">
        <h1>oh hello</h1>
        <p>
          We're Homewa,<br></br> the first property <br></br>
          search platform that <br></br>actually puts the <br></br>you first.{' '}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    // </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```

Answer (score 2):

You got a typo: `windowWidth` is not a function:

```
//                not windowWidth()
const imageUrl = windowWidth >= 600 ? chair : chairmob;
```

Also, you should set the event listener only on a mount instead on every render as it is currently set:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleWindowResize = () => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
  };

  window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
  };
}, []);
```